# REST - Is Project Checked Out

Tags: 2013, rest, project-server

I am trying  to query a PWA project set to see if it checked out (any user). There is an endpoint to check-in a draft project which is like so

```
ProjectServer/Projects(guid'xxx')/Draft/checkIn()
```

but can't find documentation around how to get information about the project check-in status.

Any pointers are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer, querying the draft project data will return project fields such as "IsCheckedOut", "CheckedOutDate" etc. which provide in-depth information about the current project check-in information. /pwa/_api/ProjectServer/ProjectData on the other hand does not provide any of the above information.

Request:

```
[HTTP/GET]
http://contoso.com/PWA/_api/ProjectServer/Projects('guid')/?$select=IsCheckedOut
```

Response:

```
<d:IsCheckedOut m:type="Edm.Boolean">true</d:IsCheckedOut></m:properties>
```

Comment: There is no such REST endpoint in PS as /pwa/_api/ProjectServer/ProjectData. You can use either /pwa/_api/ProjectServer (for processing or querying PS entities, see https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/project-javascript-api/jj669214(v=office.15)#projectserver-resources-in-the-rest-interface) or /pwa/_api/ProjectData (mostly suitable for reporting purposes, see: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/project-odata/jj163015(v%3Doffice.15)).